# Has Beast always been able to transform at will?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, continuity, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In *X-Men Days of Future Past* Beast is obviously able to transform at will. However, in the few scenes of *X1-3* he appeared in, he's always been depicted in his beast form.

Can he transform in one film but not the others?

If he always has the option of appearing human (like Mystique) why do we never see him in human form in the earlier (by release date) films?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie yet, but I think that might be a rather new addition? I've never read the comics, but I remember the cartoon show from the late 80's and he's always been in "Beast form". IIRC he also considered it being blessing and gift at once, and nothing he'd have to fight against (except possibly one episode; but that's been too long ago to remember).

Comment: “in the few scenes of X1-3 he appeared in, he's always been depicted in his beast form” — nope. He didn’t appear in *X-Men (2000)*, and [in *X2 (2003)* he had a brief cameo in human form](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/images/users/gallerypictures/22528L.jpg). [He was all-Beast in *X-Men 3 (2006)* though.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_(comics)#Film)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because he doesn't have this ability.
He transforms back to his human form because of a serum he uses that surpresses mutant powers. Beast only takes enough to turn human, but not enough to completely surpress his powers, which is why he can still transform.
Charles Xavier uses the same serum to allow him to walk at the cost of his psychic power (because of the higher dosage).